# Using JS/jQuery to make a div invisible based on the contents of a child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Context**

I have a page that is populated with several `<div>`s which are filled by parsing a JSON response after the user has submitted a search through a previous form. So far this works fine, and the resulting html roughly looks like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>some info</p>
    <img (relevant image)>
    <div class="child">value</div>
</div><!--/parent-->

<div class="parent">
    <p>some info</p>
    <img (relevant image)>
    <div class="child">value1</div>
</div><!--/parent-->

etc
```

In addition, this page has a `select` menu, the options for which are also populated by parsing the JSON response, and this `select` contains every possible `(value)` that could be found in these divs.

```
<select id="select">
    <option>value</option>
    <option>value1</option>
    <option>value2</option>
         etc...
</select>
```

It is worth mentioning some divs use the same `value`, so any given `value` may appear several times on the page, or might not appear at all, but any `div class="child"` can only hold 1 value.

**Goal**

What I'm trying to achieve, is a filter of sorts, where the user can select an option in the `select` menu. Then, only the `parent` divs which have a `child` div that contain that specific value remain visible, the rest has to disappear.

This is the script I came up with:

```
function filter() {
    var child = document.getElementsByClassName("child"),
        i, len;
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    var filter = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    for (i = 0, len = child.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (child[i].innerHTML != filter) {
            $(this).closest("div.parent").css("display", "none");
        } else {
            alert("failure")
        }
    })
};
```

The `alert` is there solely for testing purposes, so I can see if the script does anything at all. For now, the script is triggered by a button, but when it's working, I'll tie it to the `select` menu to make it trigger automatically when the user selects an option.

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Neither Chrome console nor Firefox dev tools gives an error. I simply get the alert, meaning the script deems the contents of `var filter` to be identical to `child.innerhtml`. Although this is valid for some instances of `var child`, it is not valid for all instances.

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I have also tried to replace `closest()` with `parent()`, and I have tried to replace `css(..)` by `addClass()` but to no avail.

I consider myself a novice on both JS and JQuery, so I might be missing something obvious, but I've looked extensively for answers using Google, SO, MDN, JQuery documentation and every other programming-related website I could think of (even W3schools). After more than 6 hours of searching and trying solutions, I'm at a complete loss. What am I missing here?

Comment: `getElementByClassName` => `getElementsByClassName`. You missed `s`

Comment: @Oen44 thanks for your response, that was a typo in the question, which I'll correct, but in the actual script I'm testing, I didn't make that mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with you implementation is the usage of `this`, which doesn't refers to element which you want to hide.

You can try

```
$(child[i]).closest("div.parent").css("display", "none");
```

instead of

```
$(this).closest("div.parent").css("display", "none");
```

---

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to target the div's to show

```
$("select").on('change', function filter() { 
    //Get selected value
    var selected = $(this).val();

    var parents = $("div.parent");
    //Hide All
    parents.hide();

    //Use filter() to target the divs you want to show
    parents.filter(function(){
        return $(this).find('div.child').text() === selected;
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: Using `child[i]` fixed it for me. I cannot express how happy I am this is finally working. Thank you!

Comment: I'll give that a try as well, since it's a bit neater than what I have now, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a data attribute to every `.child` div holding the specific value:

```
<div class="child" data-value="valueX">valueX</div>
```

Then, call the following function:

```
function filter() {
    var val = $('#select').val();
    var parents = $('.parent');
    // Hide all parents
    parents.hide();
    // Show paents that contain the specific value
    parents.find('child').filter('[data-value="' + val + '"]').closest('.parent').show();
}
```

---

Even better add the data attribute to the `.parent` element:

```
<div class="parent" data-value="valueX">
```

And use this function:

```
function filter() {
    var val = $('#select').val();
    var parents = $('.parent');
    // Hide all parents
    parents.hide();
    // Show paents that contain the specific value
    parents.filter('[data-value="' + val + '"]').show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but Satpal's solution solved it for me.